How does C determine whether a character is lower case (islower or isupper)?
I was looking into GNU tr in bash on Debian Linux. The regex engine appears to have a [:lower:] and [:upper:] shorthand. The regex matches on "lowercase" and "uppercase" letters. The definition of these is not trivial: is Ñ an uppercase letter? (Examples here.)
It seems to map to an "islower" function which is defined in the C language, somehow.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower
http://web.archive.org/web/20120308171350/https://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/islower/

Notice that what is considered a letter may depend on the locale being used; In the default C locale, a lowercase letter is any of: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z.


For a detailed chart on what the different ctype functions return for each character of the standard ANSII character set, see the reference for the  header.

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/1f0bf8d7c4b7131c6a8762de02ea01affef4db65/src/tr.c#L392
I can't find where islower is defined, perhaps within a specific C implementation (e.g. gcc).
It also appears to depend on the "locale". Does this occur at compile time, or live in runtime? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-2521/overview-1002/index.html

That is highly dependent on implementation. Traditionally it was common with an array, one element for each character in the full alphabet (so including control and non-printable characters, i.e. with 256 elements). Each element was a bit-mask, where a specific bit set meant that the character was a upper-case character or not. For common 8-bit encodings it might still be handled that way.

That's helpful, but tr has some definition of islower for any character I give it. How does it determine it? Is there an example implementation I could look at?

Remember that all GNU tools are open source, which means that the source is available to read. It's part of GNU coreutils whose source is available from this github repository.

And if it turns out that it's using the standard C isupper and islower, then the source for those are available as well.

There are files that contain the information for each locale installed on a system. See https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales for an introduction.

The determination of lower case letters, per locale, is commonly determined before compile time.
localeconv() [formatting of numeric quantities] allows the dynamic changing of some locale attributes, but not the determination of lower case.

The locale may change with char *setlocale(int category, const char *locale);
At program startup, the equivalent of setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); is executed.
At least 2 locales are defined:

"C": A minimal C environment.  This is defined in the spec with 'a' - 'z', and nothing else, as lower case letters.

"": Implementation's native environment.


Some implementations allow for dozens of different locales.  Some only have the minimal 2 - which might use the same determination of lower case letters - so no functional difference.
Thus the behavior of islower() can change during a program's run.

Soapbox  C's locale is an initial attempt to localize code to various country/culture standards.  Yet it is cumbersome, inadequate and incurs troubles with multi-threading.   Proceed with caution.
